# IndexOutOfBoundsException when working with a DataBase

Tags: android, database, exception, achartengine

I have next stupid situation:
I want to read data from a database and draw a chart with this data.

When my code is:

```
 package com.example.gymforyou;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;

import android.util.Log;

public class LineGraph {
    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {
        final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
        int countOfRecords = 0;
        countOfRecords=3;
        Date[] x = new Date[countOfRecords];
        double y[] = new double[countOfRecords];
        c.close();
        db.close();
        y[0]=10;
        y[1]=20;
        y[2]=34;
        x[0]=Date.valueOf("2013-04-06");
        x[1]=Date.valueOf("2013-05-06");
            x[2]=Date.valueOf("2013-06-06");
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1");
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            series.add(x[i], y[i]);
        }
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset,
            mRenderer, "dd-MM-yyyy");


    return intent;
}
```

}
-All is good;
but when i change it to:

```
    package com.example.gymforyou;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;

import android.util.Log;

public class LineGraph {
    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {
        final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
        DataBase db;
        Cursor c;
        int countOfRecords = 0;
        db = new DataBase(context);
        db.open();
        c = db.getDateAndWeigth();
        countOfRecords = c.getCount();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "countOfRecords=" + countOfRecords);
        Date[] x = new Date[countOfRecords];
        double y[] = new double[countOfRecords];

        int j = countOfRecords - 1;
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    y[j] = c.getDouble(0);
                    x[j] = Date.valueOf(c.getString(1));
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                            "Date" + c.getString(1) + " weigth= "
                                    + c.getDouble(0));
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Record #" +j+ " Secsess");
                    j--;

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cursor is null");
        c.close();
        db.close();

        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1");
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            series.add(x[i], y[i]);
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        dataset.addSeries(series);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);

        renderer.setFillPoints(true);

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    //  mRenderer.setDisplayValues(true);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);

        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

        // mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    //  mRenderer.setXTitle("Date");
    //  mRenderer.setXLabels(countOfRecords);
        ;
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset,
                mRenderer, "dd-MM-yyyy");


        return intent;
    }
}
```

It work if a have 2 records in DB, but when there are 3 records i get next errors:
[image: Error list]

I am surprised, why it works with two records from DB, 3 records from array, but did not work with 3 records from DB

Comment: 6883            int oldWidth = mRight - mLeft;

Comment: The code suggests that your app is `com.example.gymforyou` but in the error log, there don't seem to be any references to that.  Are they there but lower down, and hence not visible in the image that you posted?

Comment: No, there is no such reports

Comment: In which case, it's unclear what's causing the crash.  I suggest using a lot of `Log.d(...)` everywhere, to work out the path, and to work out what line causes the crash.  If the crash is in a different thread, you may need to comment out lines to work out where the problems is.  Good luck.

Comment: It did not crash in this part of code, a tried to put after every line Log.d()-it comes to end.